# How to get rid of the error: $parse:lexerr Lexer?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to creating dynamic states with [$stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)
Everything is working fine but when I try to create statename `standard_#_of_employees_1` then it gives me following error

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%209-9%20%5B%23%5D&p2=standard_%23_of_employees_1
t/<@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:6:450
Nb.prototype.throwError@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:159:266
Nb.prototype.lex@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:158:72
$a.prototype.parse@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:163:256
Xd/this.$get</<@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:96:107
k@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:102:227
Yd/this.$get</h.prototype.$watch@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:103:380
yd</<@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:197:75
J@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:53:345
f@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:46:399
f@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:46:416
x/<@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:46:67
Q/<@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:47:303
u@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:51:28
xd</<.link/<@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:196:394
Yd/this.$get</h.prototype.$watchCollection/<@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:105:244
Yd/this.$get</h.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:106:309
Yd/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:109:285
f@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:71:245
F@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:75:408
ve/</x.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:3001/lib/angular.min.js:76:457

<form role="form" class="form-inline ng-pristine ng-valid" id="{{Question.QuestionKey| lowercase}}" name="demographic_form" ng-submit="next(Question)" ng-show="{{Question.QuestionKey| lowercase}}">
```

Comment: You can't have a `#` in your state, if you check the url provided by the error it gives a better explanation

Comment: Would you please give any  link where i can check that i can't use # in statename??

Comment: It's in your own error, it says `Unexpected next character  at columns 9-9 [#] ` http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%209-9%20%5B%23%5D&p2=standard_%23_of_employees_1